# Why can I "save as image" a canvas in Firefox but not other browser

Tags: html, firefox, canvas

Why can I right click on a canvas in firefox and "save as image" but not in other browsers?  This even works on a tainted canvas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save HTML 5 canvas to a file in Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888812/save-html-5-canvas-to-a-file-in-chrome). Also "tainted canvas" is an excellent name for a nerd/death metal core band, gonna register it.

Comment: At a guess: because FireFox added that feature. I think it's a pretty good guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a very long time ago, back in 2006, someone filed a bug in Mozilla that you couldn't do that, and in 2007 they added the feature. [Here is the bug reported in 2006.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=346849)

Nowhere in the WHATWG/W3C canvas specification does it mention what kind of context menu the canvas ought to have. Firefox decided adding "View Image" and "Save as Image" were reasonable, other browsers have not implemented canvas-specific context menus.

It's not odd that chrome doesn't have it, it's odd that Firefox *does.* Convenient though, isn't it?